# iOS, UIPickerView create programmatically, empty view, delegates work

Tags: ios, uipickerview

@Hey everybody,

I have trouble w/ UIPickerView. I'm planning to create a view controller which should allow user to specify the one of the next day. PickerView should show strings like "wed, 1 Dec", "thu, 2 dec", etc
The problem is PickerView is empty (PickerView doesn't show any string). In spite of delegates methods return necessary count of strings and the strings themselves.

Image of empty PickerView - [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Zu9D9ZQvSVbTVMQ0ZQS1NqU2s/edit?usp=sharing)

Below is my code.

.h

```
@interface OMSDatePickerViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic        ) NSInteger     amountOfDays;
@property (nonatomic        ) CGFloat       cellHeight;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "OMSDatePickerViewController.h"

@interface OMSDatePickerViewController () {
    NSMutableArray * dateForChoose;
    NSInteger datePickerActiveIdx;

    UIPickerView *dPicker;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    dateForChoose = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 200, 150)];  

    [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)];
    [self.view setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [[self.view layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];
    [[self.view layer] setBorderWidth:2.0f];
    [[self.view layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

    // Creating the list of dates
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df.dateFormat = @"EEE',' dd MMM";

    [dateForChoose removeAllObjects];

    // Add some data for demo purposes.
    NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];
    NSString *str;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i< amountOfDays; i++, curDate = [curDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24]) {
        str = [df stringFromDate:curDate];
        [dateForChoose addObject:str];
    }


    [dPicker setDataSource: self];
    [dPicker setDelegate: self];

    dPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:dPicker];


    datePickerActiveIdx = 0;

    NSLog(@"%@", dPicker);
}
```

and delegates methods

```
// Number of components.
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

// Total rows in our component.
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"numberOfRowsInComponent: %d", [dateForChoose count]);
    return [dateForChoose count];
}

// Display each row's data.
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSString *str = [dateForChoose objectAtIndex: row];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dateForChoose objectAtIndex: row]);
    return [dateForChoose objectAtIndex: row];
}

// Do something with the selected row.
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    NSLog(@"You selected this [%2d, %2d]: %@", row, component, [dateForChoose objectAtIndex: row]);
    NSLog(@"count - %d", [dateForChoose count]);
    datePickerActiveIdx = row;
}
```

Interesting things when I try to rotate wheel "didSelectRow" is called and always return row == 0 and show:

[55215:c07] You selected this [ 0,  0]: Wed, 04 Dec

[55215:c07] count - 4

**Any ideas?**

Addition: the same code work well if it's copied to the implementation of internal function of some UIViewController. For example it's button event handler and the code is called by pressing this button.

**WHAT IS IT???***

PS: working log

```
[18241:907] viewDidLoad
[18241:907] <UIPickerView: 0x1cd944a0; frame = (5 5; 190 162); layer = <CALayer: 0x1cd94990>>
[18241:907] viewWillAppear
[18241:907] numberOfRowsInComponent: 4
[18241:907] numberOfRowsInComponent: 4
[18241:907] Wed, 04 Dec
[18241:907] Thu, 05 Dec
[18241:907] Fri, 06 Dec
[18241:907] Sat, 07 Dec
[18241:907] viewDidAppear
```

Comment: Do you see the log output from `numberOfRowsInComponent:` and `titleForRow:`?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, all delegates are called and seem to work well. I add log .

Comment: Your `viewDidLoad` is full of suspicious code. Comment out all of the "layer" code. Also, don't set the frame of the view controller's view. That's never good. And lastly, don't use the `initWithFrame:` method to create the picker. Just use `init` so it defaults to the proper size. See if all of that helps.

Comment: @rmaddy. Sorry, but there are not suspicious. Meanwhile these do not help too. Situation the same.

Comment: By "suspicious" I meant the code looked like possible candidates for the cause of the problem. Your picker code looks right. The log output is correct. It makes no sense that the picker looks empty. But really, why are you setting the frame of `self.view`? That's very unusual.

Comment: @rmaddy. It likes popup dialog and should not to ocupate all screen.

Comment: The image link is dead

Answer (score 0):

You can add/try:

```
[dPicker setDataSource: self];
[dPicker setDelegate: self];

 dPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

[self.view addSubview:dPicker];

 [dPicker reloadAllComponents]; // Should reload the data from what I understand
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not the reason. I've already tried it. Also reloading is necessary when data array is changed.